# Как получить значения ключа json?

Tags: python, json

У меня есть json файл:

```
"123": {"Имя": "Абоба", "фамилия": "Биба"}
```

Мне нужно получить значение ключа "фамилия" через python.
Ну то есть я понимаю это:

```
with open("test.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Что сделать с data, чтобы получить значение "фамилия"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для начала json должен выглядеть так:

```
{"123": {"Имя": "Абоба", "фамилия": "Биба"}}
```

напрямую можно получить так:

```
value = data["123"]["фамилия"]
```

если же вам надо получить значения для всех ключей:

```
for value in data.values():
    print(value["фамилия"])
```

Comment: json уже так выглядит. Спасибо большое